# What happens when a promoted cell that makes a capturing move is at the king-row, and there are capturing moves available?

Tags: checkers

When a capturing move of a non-promoted cell is at the king-row, the cell becomes a king cell and can't make any other capturing move even if there are available.

What about a promoted cell that makes a capturing move is at the king-row, and there are capturing moves available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All capturing moves are compulsory (with the exception of your choice of which capturing sequence to take).

It is a special case that causes a pieces movement to end when it is promoted.

In your case, the piece was already promoted before re-entering the king-row as part of a capturing sequence. Its movement does not end and you must continue to make the available capturing moves.

Answer (score 0):

For the checkers variant predominantly played in the US/UK, see the answer by @ColinD. The same rules applies to almost every other [**checkers/draughts variant**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts).

In the [**Russian draughts variant**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_draughts), however, if a man passes the king-row during a capture sequence, it **promotes and continues to jump as a king** until it is finished.